# Firebase Rules - Allow only specific users to access private chat

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm creating an application that uses Private chats to let people communicate.

I have 2 trees. One contains all the messages, and the other contains details about every chat. (*necessary to show it on "My chats" activity without loading the whole messages tree*).

**My structure is:**

[image: PrivateChatsDetails]

Each `privatechatdetails` key contains `uid1` & `uid2`, `lastMessage` node with details about the last message that has sent, and 'users' node that contains 2 users details, keys are the uids.

I want to show each user only the chats that he's in. How can I achieve that using Firebase Rules?

For now I'm using `orderByChild` & `equalTo` trick -

```
mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("privateChatsDetails").orderByChild("users/" + mUid + "/chat").equalTo(true)
```

Working perfectly, but I want to order the list by last message timestamp, so I need to do that user chats check using Firebase Database Security Rules.

Thanks in advance.